# Custom DTD in HTML 5

Tags: html, tags, dtd

I'm experimenting with custom tag in html 5.

I tried the following:

```
<my-script src='script.js' />
```

this is inside the 'head' tag in the source code - but the browser (FF \ chrome) renders it inside the body. Also, it is rendered with an extra 'closing' tag:

```
<my-script src='script.js'> </my-script>
```

And, all the content of the 'body' tag gets nested inside this custom tag (the browser is wrapping the content of 'body' with my custom tag).

I tried using a custom DTD, but just can't get it to work...any ideas anyone ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this ...?

Comment: HTML5 doesn't use DTDs, so whatever you're trying, it won't work that way.

Comment: Maybe you can try the trick from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla) - using a `<script>` with a different `type` allows you to put other data in a HTML file (the example is with XML, but you could experiment with your type of choice).

Answer (score 1):

Browsers treat a tag like `<my-script src='script.js' />` as the start tag of an unknown element (except if the page is served with an XML content type). Since such a tag is not allowed within `head`, it implicitly closes the `head` element and starts the `body` element.

DTDs have nothing to do with this, since browsers don’t even read DTDs (and there is no DTD for HTML5, and it is impossible to write a DTD that matches HTML5 syntax rules).

So, in effect, you cannot use a custom element inside the `head` element. If you wish to use a custom element with no content, put it inside the `body` element and write it with the end tag spelled out: `<my-script src='script.js'></my-script>`. That way, it will not affect the display or the parsing of the page, and will have no effect except via client-side scripting that accesses it via the DOM.